# Cannot run program, CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied: CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied

Tags: android

I am using Android studio. I wanted to share my project on github but I had lots of issues doing it.

First of all, the Android studio couldnt find git.exe. Somehow I could solve that issue but right now the problem is the next one:

Cannot run program. Creat process error 5. Access is denied.

Could not find a way to solve this. Could you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Just add git.exe to the end of "Path to Git Executable:" field.

Answer (score 0):

"Path to Git Executable:"

Try this: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem with Java (Android & flutter development) and It turns out that Avast was the one blocking it from running. After add the path `"C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.282.8-hotspot\jre\bin\java"` to avast exception list. everything works fine.

Check if your anitvirus is not blocking it.